# Necessary and sufficient conditions for convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1$ (given convergence in measure)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is the following "conjecture" true?

(I'm pretty sure my proof for this is sound and so i'd like to be assured that it's not wrong at least).

> Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space and  $f_n, f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$
>   integrable functions. $f_n \to f$ in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ if and only if the
>   following three conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1) $f_n \to f$ in measure
>
> 2) $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a uniformly integrable collection.
>
> 3) For every $\epsilon >0$ there's $E \subset X$ 
>   satisfying: $\mu(E) < \infty$ and $\int_{X -E}|f_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n  \in \mathbb{N}$

If it is true is there some topological way of understanding it?

(Something along the lines of "convergence in measure defines a topology on the space $\mathcal{L}^1$ then consider...").

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is known as (a form of) the **Vitali convergence theorem**. But you have to write $\int_{X\setminus E} |f_n| < \varepsilon$ in the last condition (note the absolute value).

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance! and sorry about the typo - it's fixed now.